# Softmax Tensorflow Lite not behaving properly

Tags: android, tensorflow, softmax, tensorflow-lite

I've made a simple convolutional Tensorflow model which uses softmax for inference. When I run the model in python and feed the model an image everything works accordingly. However when I convert the model with tflite and run it from android the output is a list of all 0's. Somehow the softmax is not working. When I remove the softmax function the output is the same in python and android, I'm able to fix it by implementing a softmax function in Java but there should be better way right? I've tried changing the axis of the softmax function but it keeps only returning 0's in Java.

Thank you!

```
y_test = tf.nn.softmax(test_network[0])
```

Comment: It is very strange that the output is full of zeros for softmax. Could you please give a sample of input where the output is a list of zeros? Also, if you are using quantized version, what is the [SoftmaxParams](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/20e1089c40941f585f0e4a1918b29272f078d5d0/tensorflow/lite/kernels/internal/optimized/optimized_ops.h#L4101) when the kernel is called? The beta or the input_multiplier or the input_left_shift are very critical.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you use the quantized graph. TFLite compute softmax in floating point, then multiply it by 256 and store as uint8. As most of the values are very small, therefore after multiplication and rounding up to nearest integers, they will be zeros. However, the ranking should be the same, if you want to display softmax, you can divide them by 256 to show the top few values that are non-zero.